# Corona Lua waveform sound synthesis

Tags: audio, lua, coronasdk

I would like to make a sound synth using the Corona SDK, which means in pure Lua. All the Lua synth programs rely on an underlying C program. Is there any Lua library that generates waveforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience when it comes to Audio.

But here are a couple of links to get you started!

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/07/27/the-secretundocumented-audio-apis-in-corona-sdk/

http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2012/02/09/drone-fx

Comment: I guess the best bet is to use Corona's pseudo-supported OpenAL API.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Corona has an audio API that would allow that, but the MOAI SDK is a free, open source, Lua-based engine that targets iOS (+ Android, PC, Mac, Linux) which you could add anything you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Corona SDK has very weak sound support, and there are not good Lua audio libraries that I know of. MOAI appears to be dead, or mostly dead.

AudioKit seems like the way to write synthesis these days, but it is Swift & Objective-C only. Would love to see it in Lua, but there does not seem to be a push in that direction:

http://audiokit.io/